# How to group gates manually (and make circuit more readable)?

Tags: qiskit

I'm trying to make my circuit look readable, but the gates auto-order in Qiskit QuantumCircuit shifts all gates to the left side.
For example an image from [qiskit documentation](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.html):

[image]

It would be much better to put ancilla X gate into the first column, Hadamard gats into the second, controlled gates into the third-fourth-fifth, and last Hadamard into the sixth column.

Such a result may be achieved in [Quirk](https://algassert.com/quirk#circuit=%7B%22cols%22:%5B%5B1,1,1,%22X%22%5D,%5B%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22%5D,%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22,1,1,%22X%22%5D,%5B1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,1,%22X%22%5D,%5B1,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22X%22%5D,%5B%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22%5D%5D%7D) [image: quirkAnalogue]

Is there a way to set up an explicit column number for the quantum gate in the Qiskit QuantumCircuit (or other class)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `barrier`s to align the gates:

```py
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
circuit = QuantumCircuit(4)
circuit.x(3)
circuit.barrier()
circuit.h(range(4))
circuit.cx([0,1,2], 3)
circuit.h(range(3))
circuit.measure_all()
circuit.draw('mpl')
```

[image: circuit with barriers]

If you want to remove them from the plot:

```py
circuit.draw('mpl', plot_barriers=False)
```

[image: same circuit, aligned, no barriers showed]